# Facebook Graph API Query: Find all friends of a certain gender

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm working on moving my app's code from Facebook's deprecated FQL to the graph API. Overall, the API makes a lot of sense thanks to the graph explorer tool. I've been able to figure out how to make general queries such as getting all my friends (and each friend's gender, first name, last name, and profile picture):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.2/me?fields=friends{gender,first_name,last_name,picture}
```

The main issue I'm running into is figuring out how to make my query more specific. What I really want to do is get all my friends who are females. How would I go about specifying a desired 'gender' here? Is this even possible? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Filtering via query is not possible with the current version of the Graph API. You'll have to filter the result of your request in your application unfortunately.

Comment: Wow, good to know. Thanks for your answer. Going to wait a day or so and if no other answers, then I'll mark yours as the accepted one.